# How to separate MUI setup to an external js file?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this MUI codes that are applied to multiple components. I want to separate it into a single file like 'MuiSetup.js' and then import the file to the component that I am using. I've tried with as React component, however, it does not work and I have zero clues how can I do this.

```
// Styling TextField
const ValidationTextField = withStyles({
  root: {
    '& input:valid + fieldset': {
      borderColor: '#ff9800',
      borderWidth: 1,
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      '&:hover fieldset': {
        borderColor: '#ff9800',
      },
      '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
        borderColor: '#ff9800',
      },
    },
    '& input:invalid + fieldset': {
      borderColor: '#ff9800',
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'black',
    },

    '& input:valid:focus + fieldset': {
      borderColor: '#ff9800',
      borderLeftWidth: 5,
      padding: '4px !important', // override inline-style
    },
  },
})(TextField);

//Style MUI
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    height: '100vh',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  input: {
    color: '#ff9800',
  },
  formBackground: {
    background: 'black',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  paper: {
    margin: theme.spacing(8, 4),
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  form: {
    width: '100hv',
    height: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(0),
    color: '#ff9800',
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
  },
}));


//Label Style
const useLabelStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    color: '#ff9800',
    '&.Mui-focused': {
      color: '#ff9800',
    },
    fontSize: '14px',
  },
});

-----------
const App = () => {......}
export default App
```

How can I take the MUI part to the separated file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of my projects I actually used  `createMuiTheme()` in another file then added my own classes under the `overrides`. Then the entire app is wrapped in the `ThemeProvider` which you pass in your custom theme. Then you can just give the component a `className`.

So my `MuiSetup.js` equivalent file looks something like this:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core';

// Describe material ui theme
export const customTheme = (isDark = false) => {
    return createMuiTheme({
        palette: isDark
            ? {
                    common: {...},
                    background: {...},
                    primary: {...},
                    secondary: {...},
                    error: {...},
                    text: {...},
              }
            : {// Light theme stuff},
        overrides: {
            MuiAppBar: {...},
            MuiButton: {
                // Button example...
                root: {
                    '&.CustomButton': {
                        margin: 0,
                    },
                    '&.OtherCustomButton': {
                        width: '100%',
                        minHeight: 'inherit',
                    },
                    '&$disabled': {
                        color: grey[600],
                    },
                },
                outlinedSecondary: {
                    '&$disabled': {
                        border: `1px solid ${grey[600]}`,
                    },
                },
            },
            // Other mui components...
        },
    });
};
```

You'll need to read the API docs to find your inputs.

Then the `ThemeProvider`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';
import { customTheme } from './MuiSetup.js';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const currentTheme = customTheme(true);
        
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={currentTheme}>
                <h1>My app</h1>

                // Usage
                <Button className='CustomButton'/>

            </ThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Then from any component within the app, you can do: `<Button className='CustomButton'/>` as I've done above.

Not sure if this is the best way, might be a bit tricky to make multiple updates however you could do something similar in your situation and create a function in another file that returns your custom `makeStyles`.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, to put these customizations in a separated file is just necessary to define them in aseparated file with the key "export const ..." and then, when you want to import them, just write:

```
import { ValidationTextField } from "./muiCustomizations"; // supposing that you defined your customizations in a file called muiCustomizations.js
```

and then you can use them:

```
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ValidationTextField />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-textfield-forked-elzv3?file=/src/index.js) a codesandbox example.